# HTML Centered Tiles

Tags: html, css

I'd like to design a horizontal line of tiles. Ideally I'd like something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/BDb5K/     found in another post by GolezTrol.

But centered. I have a lot of trouble centering  elements, and these have been no exception. What is the best way to center (and space out) a structure like this?

EDIT: this is what I want - https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KWWI.png

Comment: Define *centered*... Is this to the page? the parent? each row? the image container?

Comment: centered horizontally or vertically? and what is centered the text or the div or what.... maybe drawing a picture in mspaint and posting that will help us understand. using tables for layout is usually a good idea for centering stuff.

Comment: like this http://i.imgur.com/5DIOk.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to give the `#container` element a fixed width and then apply this style:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

That will work for horizontal alignment, if you're after vertical alignment as well take a look at [this page](http://pmob.co.uk/pob/hoz-vert-center.htm) which has a working example for most (if not all) browsers.

Comment: +1 for beating me to the same answer. I was busy *fiddling*: http://jsfiddle.net/BDb5K/10/

Comment: this did not seem to work :S
EDIT: Sorry I misread, it works, thank you!

Comment: I've added a link in the answer in case you're looking for vertical alignment as well

Comment: but how can I space them out this way?

Comment: They'll space out naturally depending on the width you give the `#container` element. You can apply `text-align:center;` to `#container div` to center the content within each 'cell'. If you can't get the desired effect quite quickly I really wouldn't bother banging your head against a wall, just use tables. Semantically you could argue that the grid of images you're representing could easily be a table of content so it'd be fine.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have a "religious" objection to tables, they may be your best solution.